# What is the meaning of - in cat file -

Tags: linux, cat

I recently had to use some code that was given to me, and in it the is this line

```sh
cat file -
```

Did someone know what the `-` mean.

Comment: This is not bash-specific behavior; `cat` would behave the same way invoked with any other shell or with no shell at all.

Comment: This is documented in the man page for `cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-` means "read from standard input" (this is a POSIX convention). Try this in your shell and you'll see `cat` repeat everything you type:

```
$> cat -
```

Comment: Ever-so-slightly more nuanced: "read from standard input" in an input position, "write to standard output" in an output position.